# SQL Server - Trace flag 8041 - no documentation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Has anyone encountered trace flag 8041 in the wild, and can you explain what it does?

I inherited a SQL Server 2016 (13.0.5865.1) and there are some trace flags enabled. One of them is 8041. I've searched online but haven't find any thing.

Keep in mind these are databases that are migrated from, SQL Server 2005 => 2008 R2 => 2016, long before I came along. So it might be something from 2005. Or it might be nothing, but I would like to know the impact before disabling it.

Comment: Could you please put code sample where this trace is used and have you tried comparing the execution plan and other details with the traceflag and without it?

Comment: The trace is on globally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This trace flag existed for a brief moment in time but hasn't existed since. It was originally implemented in CTP 5 and 6 for Katmai (2008) and never documented. It was then removed and has been a no-op since.

While it might be listed in books or blogs, trace flags can and do change. Many are version dependent and some stay, but change, even across versions (look at 4199 for example).

This TF currently does nothing since the CTP days.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from *Beginning Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Administration* by Chris Leiter, Dan Wood, Michael Cierkowski, Albert Boettger:-

```
The following code shows how to re-set the Resource Governor statistics that are reported by the resource pool and workload group management views. You may want to do this after making significant configuration changes to the Resource Governor.

DBCC TRACEON (8041, -1)
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE
```